# updating array in firestore error : AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'items' with Python

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to update my Firestore collection with a list of strings from python.

My list:

```
results = ['link1','link2']
```

My Firestore document is 01
Collection in document is as follow:

> links (map) ----> List_of_all_links (array)----> this list should have 2 strings
> 0:link1
> 1:link2

SINCE i am coding using python, I added this :

```
db.collection(u'myjob').document(u'01').update(results)
```

> **Error: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'items'**

For now, I have the map and the array in my firestore but without strings. Any help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For you to update your array elements you need to use `arrayUnion()` to add data and `arrayRemove()` to remove the previous data. For example:

```
old_results = ['link1','link2']
new_results = ['link3','link4']

links_ref = db.collection(u'myjob').document(u'01')
# Add new data from array links
links_ref.update({u'links': firestore.ArrayUnion(new_results)})

# Remove old data from array links
links_ref.update({u'links': firestore.ArrayRemove(old_results)})
```